# bash pipe limit

Tags: bash, sed, limit, pipe, wget

i got a txt list of urls i want to download

```
n=1
end=`cat done1 |wc -l`
while [ $n -lt $end ]
do
nextUrls=`sed -n "${n}p" < done1`
wget -N nH --random-wait -t 3 -a download.log -A$1 $nextUrls 
let "n++"
done
```

i want to do it faster with pipes but if i do this

```
 wget -N nH --random-wait -t 3 -a download.log -A$1 $nextUrls &
```

my ram fills up and blocks my PC completely.
Any1 know how to limit pipes created to like 10 at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating pipes (`|`), you are creating background processes (`&`). Everytime your `while` executes its body, you create a new `wget` process and don't wait for it to exit, which (depending on the value of `end`) may create *lot* of `wget` processes very fast. Either do sequentially (remove the `&`) or you can try [executing *n* processes in parallel and wait for them](http://pebblesinthesand.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/a-srcipt-for-running-processes-in-parallel-in-bash/).

BTW, useless use of `cat`: you can simply do:

```
end=`wc -l done1`
```

Comment: `for ARG in  $@; do
    command $ARG &
    NPROC=$(($NPROC+1))
    if [ "$NPROC" -ge 4 ]; then
        wait
        NPROC=0
    fi
done` how to combine this with code above?

Comment: Directly after your `wget ... &` line, put this: `NPROC=$(($NPROC+1)) ; if [ "$NPROC" -ge 4 ]; then wait ; NPROC=0 ; fi` This will execute `wget` in parallel and once four are running, it waits until *all* of them have finished. Then continues spawning the next ones.

Answer (score 1):

> i got a txt list of urls i want to download... i want to do it faster..

So here's a shortest way to do that. The following command downloads the URL from the list contained in file *txt_list_of_urls* parallely running 10 threads:

```
xargs -a txt_list_of_urls -P 10 -r -n 1 wget -nv
```

Comment: `xargs` is a very powerful command. you should read more about this on `man xargs`.